# eclipse JCDE: error in running java card project

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I have followed exact instructions from the link [eclipse-jcde](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/), and now I have all JCDE features in my eclipse (I'm using eclipse ver 4.3.1). I made a new java card project and added new applet file to it, but when I try to run the project it shows below error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/String

and this is my (empty!) code:

```
package myPackage;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {

private MyApplet() {
}

public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
        throws ISOException {
    new MyApplet().register();
}

public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

what should I do?

Comment: The installation steps clearly say that you should use Eclipse 3.2. Eclipse 4 is a totally different environment. Often plugins for Eclipse 3 also run in v4 but it looks like eclipse-jcde does not.

Comment: thanks robert, but when I try to run eclipse 3.2 on my computer it terminates with an error, I tested two copy of it but both shows same error. I'm using windows7 64bit, do you have any idea what is my problem?

Comment: Install an old Java 1.6 32bit VM that is only used by this old Eclipse version. You can edit eclipse.ini and add the `-vm` parameter for specifying the 1.6 JVM path.

Comment: thanks again Robert, I did what you said and I think it works fine. I mean now I can covert, generate script, run script and so on but I'm not sure what is the right routine to simulate my applet. would you please help me? how can I use the JCDWE and CREF simulators?

Comment: @electro : did you receive any answer for your last question? **[how can I use the JCDWE and CREF simulators?]**. can you help me to use CREF or JCDWE?